# performance decrease with two foreach loop?

Tags: swiftui

performance decrease in two foreach loop?

the code in below , is one foreach loop,the performance is well,but i need to build mutiple scrollview.

```
ScrollView(){
        VStack(spacing: 10){
        Text("Water")
        LazyVGrid(columns: layout2, spacing: 20){
        ForEach(Array(Waters.enumerated()), id: \.element){ (index,item) in

         Button(action: {}, label: {
                                })
                            }
                        }
}
```

so I made two foreach loops like below, then the performance is decrease and lag.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false){
            HStack(spacing: 25){
                ForEach(Array(total.enumerated()), id: \.element){ (index1,item1) in
                        VStack(spacing: 15){
                            Text(item1.name)        
                            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
                            LazyVGrid(columns:Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: item1.grip), spacing: 20){
                                ForEach(Array(item1.playeritem.enumerated()), id: \.element){(index,item) in 

         Button(action: {    
           audiocontrol.tota[index1].playeritem[index].player.play()
}, label: { })
}}}
```

Is the two foreach loop cause the performance decrease?
I have totally 100 - 150 element

I remove the scollview and change enumerated to indice,the performance is better but still lag.
maybe i should only use one foreach loop

Comment: What do you mean by "the performance decrease?" In what way? How are you measuring it? The second example is much more complex than the first; why would you expect the performance to be the same? You're doing a lot of `.enumerated()` and `Array(...)` which greatly complicate things, add overhead, possibly break optimizations, and don't appear necessary. Have you tried removing all of that extra overhead?

Comment: so the .enumerated() and Array(...) can break optimizations?  ok i will removing all of that extra overhead thanks. @Rob Napier

Comment: How large are the datasets for `total` and `total.item1`? This structure isn't scalable too large and a performance hit would be expected. For example if your data sets are 10 and 10 you'd loop `O(n*n)` meaning you'd hit at least 100 times. If your datasets are larger, the worse it becomes. Think about `100*100`. Also changing from a ScrollView to a list might help, or to wrap that scrollview in a `Lazy`

Comment: All item is about 100 element, total 8 . i think i should use the first one @xTwisteDx

Comment: SwiftUI's ForEach has optimizations to avoid recomputing child Views that don't change. It works most easily when it can use Identifiable directly. The more layers of computation you add, the more likely you are to break that piece. Beyond that, more basically, it's making a lot more copies whenever anything changes. Rather than computing a lot of indexes and subscripts, get the data into the form you want in the ViewModel, and then just pass those into the ForEach.

Comment: Also agreed w/ xTwisteDx, the ScrollView is very wasteful here. You're computing all the rows every time anything changes, even though only a small number of them are visible. The point of List is to handle that in a lazy way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you tried using a List instead of ForEach? Lists are more performable than ForEach, and interpolating them can bring a little lag to your app.

Comment: the list can't scroll horizontally, i need to find another way